# Is Azure Free Website IP address needed in order to "Add to Allowed IP Addresses"?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I set up a simple asp.net web forms test site for learning Azure, with a simple DB. Works fine locally. I deployed it to Azure. Then went through learning curve on the need to separately deploy the DB, link the resource, check connection strings and so on.

There's an issue, where the program on the site gets an error.  I'm going through many paths to try to diagnose it.  This question is about one specific path.

Several articles say that for the website to use the DB, I have to add the IP address of the website to the allowed IP addresses of the DB server.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-create-configure/

However, I can't find the IP address for my FREE Azure website.  When I researched this, it looks like there is no available fixed IP address for free websites.

So either:

1) I need to know where to get the IP address for the free website, or 
 2) there is some way to use Azure SQL in free websites without having to
   designate an allowed IP address, or
 3) something completely different.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

UPDATE:  Below is all I see on the database configuration page, i.e. no firewall rules.  However, I became convinced that the "Allowed IP Address" requirement must be finessed automagically in Azure, and so that was likely NOT the problem, which made me look more closely at the connection string, which WAS the problem.  Basically one day of newbie learning curve, which I'll have to sleep on and try to understand more tomorrow.

[image: DB Configuration Tab Image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do that for things that are hosted within the Azure platform.

Under the Azure SQL Server Firewall ([Preview Portal](http://portal.azure.com)) settings, ensure that the `Allow access to Azure services` is turned on:

[image: Firewall Settings]

Alternatively, via the [Old Portal](http://manage.windowsazure.com), the setting is found via:

```
Databases -> Servers -> Configure
```

[image: Database Configuration]

Comment: I resolved this, see Update above.  I found the Allow Access controls. I could not find the Firewall controls, per the Update in my post above.  It would be helpful to know where they are.  Any clue as to why I'm not finding them?

Comment: You seem to be using the classic portal (manage.windowsazure.com) whereas my screenshot is for the preview portal (portal.azure.com)

Comment: yep, preview portal it is.  Grazie.

Comment: No problem.  Also, if one of the answers helped you solve the issue you were having, it'd be a good idea to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's an option to allow Azure services when you configure the database firewall. Check if that's checked. Also, posting the actual error message will help.

Comment: Please see comment back to Brendan about not finding Firewall controls.